# Is there a better way to do this linq sort?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following linq statement that is ordering a list of assets by the sort order of a child item:

```
 Assets.OrderBy(a => a.GalleryItems != null &&
                a.GalleryItems.FirstOrDefault(gi => gi.ProductItemCode == productId) != null
                     ? a.GalleryItems.FirstOrDefault(gi => gi.ProductItemCode == productId).SortOrder : 1000);
```

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this as I would have thought having to do 2 `a.GalleryItems.FirstOrDefault(gi => gi.ProductItemCode == productId)` would be pretty poor for performance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct, it *can* be costly.

You can just expand the lambda expression:

```
Assets.OrderBy(a => {
    var item = a.GalleryItems != null 
               ? a.GalleryItems.FirstOrDefault(gi => gi.ProductItemCode == productId)
               : null;
    return item != null ? item.SortOrder : 1000;
});
```

[Quick edit]

The above will work correctly only for LINQ 2 Objects queries.

If you're using EF or any other LINQ database provider, you should leave the query as-is, because it will probably be translated to `ISNULL(..., 1000)` or something equivalent.

Comment: This was what I was after - I was wondering if you could set vars in a lamda, now I know.  Thanks!

Comment: @Pete One important thing here though: it will only work in LINQ 2 Objects. If you're using any database LINQ driver, expanded lambda expressions are not translatable to SQL, at least not by any provider I know. On the other hand, the performance considerations and query structure are also different, since the query will is executed in the database. I added that as an edit so it's clear.

Comment: Ah, I think I'm fine as it is just querying a c# object from cache rather than the db